# how to use a jquery variable in rails hash as a key

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a hash "c_failures_all" with some values in it and i am capturing value of selected item from a dropdown list in variable "selVal" using jquery. That "selVal" will act as a key in my hash. The problem is selVal is a jquery variable and if do

```
c_failures_all[selVal]
```

throws an error  "undefined local variable or method `selVal' for #<#:0x15484300>"

```
    c_failures_all = {"Amount"=>[5, 4, 8, 7, 6], "Lookup"=>[10, 85, 56, 23, 10], "Advantage"=>[9, 5, 40, 12, 3]}
<script>
         $("#error_error_id").on('change', function(){
        //alert('f')
        var selVal = $("#error_error_id").val();
        if(selVal == "All" || selVal == '')
        {
            options.series = [{name: 'All', data: <%= c_failures_arr %>}]
        }
        else
        {
            options.series = [{name: 'D', data: <%= c_failures_all[selVal] %>}]
        }
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JS, you can create an array to access it later in ruby:

```
<script>
   var arrayFailures  = <%= c_failures_arr.to_json %>;
   $("#list").on('change', function(){
            var selVal = $("#list").val();
            if(selVal == "All" || selVal == '')
            {
                options.series = [{name: 'All', data: arrayFailures[selVal] }]
            }
            else
            {
                options.series = [{name: 'other', data: [4,7,9,6,2]}]
            }
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
<script>
```

I've not tested it, tell me if it works properly.

Comment: Louis its not working,buddy is there any way i could track down what values arrayFailures[selVal] is returning?